# Function call after Value is changed

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, hidden-field

Im trying to get a Logout button which first unsets the sessions and then closes the actual tab.
So far I only got the part with the session destroy and I can't figure out how to get the Tab close done.
I tried echo'ing that function after the sessions are destroyed, with setIntervals but I didn't manage to get that done. Anyone knows some tipps? Thanks!
Edit : all code is on the same page

Here's my code :

[HTML]

```
<input type="hidden" name="vLogout" value="false">
<input type="button" value="Logout" name="Logging out" onClick="logout(this.form)" style="background-color:#cc0000;color:#ffffff">
```

[PHP]
This is the very first line of code after `<?php`

```
if($_REQUEST["vLogout"])
{
session_start();

session_unset();
session_destroy();
echo "<script>closeTab();</script>";
}
```

[Javascript]

```
function logout(f)
{
var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to logout?");
    if (confirmed){
    f.method="post";
    f.vLogout.value = true;
    f.submit();
    }
}

function closeTab(){
    confirm("test");
//window.open(document.URL,'_self','resizable=no,top=-245,width=250,height=250,scrollbars=no');
//window.close();
}
```

Comment: As you can't call `session_start()` after any output has been sent to the browser (like well formed HTML) - you should **never** be outputting Javascript code like that, because it just can't possibly be where it should be in the code. If it's all in the same page, set a variable flag saying eg. `$closeWindow = true` then check for that later on when you've produced a correct page markup structure, **then** you can call your function.

Comment: try to change `onClick="logout(this.form)"` to `onClick="logout(document.form)"`

Comment: @scrowler Thanks alot, that was the tipp I was needing! Got it working  like I wanted to. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Most probably, you can not close a tab with JS for security issue. You can only close a tab with JS what is opened with JS.

You can use JQuery. Do not submit the form. Send Ajax request to server with onclick event. When dataType of Ajax request is 'script', browser will execute response body as JS.

note: save files (index.php and logout.php) in same directory.

in index.html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Logout</title>
      <style>
      .logout-button {
        background:#00aaee;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="logout-button">logout</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function closeTab(){
        confirm("test");
        //your code here
      }

      $('.logout-button').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: ('logout.php'),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'script'
          });
      });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

in logout.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

echo "closeTab();";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, moved some thing now it's working like the one I tried to - just easier and less space consuming. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function logout(f)
...
    f.submit();
```

You are actually submitting the form which results in a *new* document being requested, i.e. when the php script is done and its output `<script>closeTab();</script>` has been transmitted to the client, there is no function `closeTab` ..anymore.
There's also no guarantee that your javascript code is allowed to close that particular window, so I'd suggest letting your php script print out a complete html document that *tries* to close the window/tab but also displays some information for the user just in case the script fails.

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding this line in logout(f) function.

```
f.dataType = 'script';
```

logout function should be:

```
function logout(f)
{
    var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to logout?");
    if (confirmed){
      f.method="post";
      f.dataType = 'script'; //this line should be added
      f.vLogout.value = true;
      f.submit();
    }
}
```

in php code write script without script tag:

```
echo "closeTab();";
```

it should work.

Comment: doesn't work out, it just echo's "closeTab();" in the very beginning. :(

Answer (score 0):

use session_start(); in top of the page and not in any function

and than onClick="logout(this.form)" to onClick="logout(document.form)"

use input type=submit. not "Button"  and on place of $_REQUEST["vLogout"] use
        if(isset($_POST["vLogout"])) or if(isset($_GET["vLogout"]))